# Decode JSON with Java

Tags: java, json, json-simple

I am trying to decode JSON data with Java. I found a library at the following link:
http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples

I have included the .jar file in the build path in my eclipse project, which added the library under "Referenced Libraries". But when I try to use the library as shown in the first example in the link above, the type is not found.

```
String s="[0,{\"1\":{\"2\":{\"3\":{\"4\":[5,{\"6\":7}]}}}}]";
Object obj=JSONValue.parse(s);
// Error: JSONValue cannot be resolved
```

I know this question may be a bit naive, but can someone point out what step I am doing wrong?

The list of imports so far are:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;    
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONStringer;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have downloaded json-simple-1.1-bundle.jar, instead, you should download the fourth one:json_simple-1.1.jar

Answer (score 0):

Did you... forget to `import` it?

Comment: I tried using Ctrl+Shift+O in eclipse but I guess the necessary imports were not added.

Comment: @Jake: Did you properly reference the library? Also edit your question and add the exact error message.

Comment: I can see the library in the "Referenced libraries" section in my eclipse project folder hierarchy.

Comment: @Jake: Could you take a look at the imports yourself and see if it was properly imported? If you're unsure, could you paste all the imports in the question.